# npm install cypress throws an error on node16

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, package.json, nvm

Since migrating from node14 to node16, cypress is not being installed on 'npm install' and throws an error:

[image]

i think iv tried everything from reinstalling node16 to using 'sudo npm install'

its solved by either switching to node14 OR erasing the cypress line from package.json, but i need node16+cypress.

my 'nvm ls':

[image]

this issue is related to is-installed-globally npm package and it won't let me install it as well

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, to be honest. Parameter-free catch (aka [Optional catch binding](https://2ality.com/2017/08/optional-catch-binding.html)) is supported in Node since version 10.0.0 (here's [the PR](https://github.com/jquery/esprima/issues/1953)). Are you sure the Node which runs this particular script is the correct one? Using `nvm` might be confusing sometimes...

Comment: How can i further make sure other than 'nvm ls'?
i re-downloaded and installed node16 as well: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `npm` itself is out of alignment with node. Try updating with

```js
npm update npm -g
```

then re-install Cypress

Comment: doesn't seem to do the trick :/
i also re-installed node16: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who finds this in the future.

I was having the same trouble described above. The new version of cypress works with node 16.

- node version 16.14.2
- cypress.io version 10.0.3